# How can I construct a where clause in C#/EF Core with the field defined at runtime?

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core

This seems simple, but I can't decipher the LINQ required to do it.  I also can't add any new dependencies.

Basically, I'm trying to make this code generic:

```
if (filter.matchMode.ToUpper().Equals("EQ")) {
  query = query.Where(x => x.SomeField.Equals(filter.Value));
if (filter.matchMode.ToUpper().Equals("LT")) {
  query = query.Where(x => x.SomeField < filter.Value);
} else [... 5 other match modes ...]
}
```

Now, `SomeField` is only one of about 5 fields that needs this functionality.  And there's 5 matching operators.  I could just copy/pasta the whole thing, and then deal with the debt of having to change tons of code every time a new operator or field enters the mix, but that *really* doesn't seem right.

Basically, I need some way of defining `SomeField` at runtime, so I can factor out the whole if/else tree and use it for each supported field.

I've tried going down this road, but I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about expressions:

```
var entityType = typeof(TableObject);
ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
MemberExpression amproperty = Expression.Property(arg, "SomeField");
MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(amproperty, "Equals"); // ???
// what's next, if this is even the right direction...
```

EDIT: a shorter version of the question might be: how can I construct the following object `foo` using `MemberExpression`s and lambdas, such that `SomeField` can be passed in as a string `"SomeField"`:

```
Expression<Func<TableObject, bool>> foo = x => x.SomeField.Equals("FOO");
```

UPDATE: here's what I ended up coming up with:

```
private IQueryable<TableObject> processFilter(
    IQueryable<TableObject> query,
    FilterItem filter,
    string fieldName)
{
    var entityType = typeof(TableObject);

    // construct the argument and access object
    var propertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty(fieldName);
    ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
    MemberExpression access = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(arg,
        typeof(TableObject).GetProperty(fieldName)
    );


    // translate the operation into the appropriate Expression method
    Expression oprFunc;
    if (filter.MatchMode.ToUpper().Equals("EQ")) {
        oprfunc =
            Expression.Equal(access, Expression.Constant(filter.Value));
    } else if (filter.MatchMode.ToUpper().Equals("LT")) {
        oprfunc =
            Expression.LessThan(access, Expression.Constant(filter.IntValue));
    } else {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $"invalid argument: ${filter.MatchMode}"
        );
    }

    // construct the lambda
    var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<TableObject, bool>>(oprFunc, arg);

    // return the new query
    return query.Where(func);
}
```

So far, this seems to cover most of the cases.  It starts to go off the rails with nullable fields and date comparisons, but it will work for what I need it to do.  The part I'm still not completely sure about is `Expression.MakeMemberAccess`.  I've seen this written many ways and I'm not sure if that's the correct way to create that expression.

Comment: In my experience with MemberExpressions, it's easier to ask the caller to provide the property as an `Expression<Func<T>>` so the caller passes the field in as `() => x.SomeField` and you can then cast the expression body to a MemberExpression, then take the Member property and cast that to PropertyInfo and use the PropertyInfo to get the value from the object on which `SomeField` lives.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to pass in `x.SomeField` as a parameter.  `Expression<Func<TableObject>>` doesn't do it.  Even if I could, how do I then shove it into the `Where()` call.

Comment: Can you provide some more sample code leading up to the execution of these match modes are evaluated? It's unclear to me where the object containing `SomeField` is coming from

Comment: Have a look into [this project](https://github.com/AlexanderKrutov/DataTables.Queryable) It's pretty much what you are trying to do. It helped me a lot in understanding Expressions.

Comment: For example, [here](https://github.com/AlexanderKrutov/DataTables.Queryable/blob/817be59fbe7d66313709b5d374fd49c84705478f/DataTables.Queryable/QueryableExtensions.cs#L332) you can see `string.Contains`. Basicly you need an expression for every operator.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have class like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public string a1 {  get; set; }
    public string b1 {  get; set; } 
    public string c1 {  get; set; }
}
```

also let's assume you have method like this:

```
public List<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria )
{
    return someDataLINQCapable.Where(criteria);
}
```

Method could be called like this:

```
GetAll<SomeClass>(m => m.a1 != null && m.b1=="SomethingUseful")
```

Comment: now factor that out so that I can call `GetAll<SomeClass>("a1", "eq", "SomethingUseful");`  That's what I need.

Comment: Well, in example of your where clause you r passing an expression, which you r building using a middle man. What I am suggesting is: cut the middle man.